# When login/sign-up are walls and when they not?

Tags: login

I'm re-building the entire experience of a social media app and i really improved it former onboarding, but suddenly I found and read this article of the [NNGroup about Login Walls](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/login-walls/) and the bad experience that that these could put into the users.

As a new startup my client needs as much people getting registered as possible and just because of this I'm thinking of get rid of login or sign up, let the users get in, discover what the app is offering for them, and then if they want to stay and get deep in it just make a login.

So my question is...why it would be a good idea let people enter to the app without any registration or login?
I've seen some apps with **guest** button, is this a better idea than just a totally open door?

Is this more a survey than a question? Yes, it might, but I'm losing my mind with this and need another perspective.

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to know the reasons why it would be better to let users use the app before login in. Does this apply to your case? What is exactly the difference between an open door and a guest button?

Comment: Alvaro, i think the only difference between one and another is just is one more step.
I can't figure out if in terms of perception could be so much different.
What do you think about it?

Comment: In my opinion, trying the app lets me use the main functionality with some constraint (time, features, etc.). While being a guest implies seeing around more than participating or using the app as a logged in user. But this is just my impression.

Comment: @Alvaro yes, i think you are completely right about de difference, thank you so so much

Answer (score 2):

I think there are more than just 100% public or 100% private options when it comes to dealing with the "Sign Up Wall" situation.

Take a look at Glassdoor. They are an employer review site, they do a very good job at balancing this line of showing/hiding application features/content to the public. In my opinion, they give non-members just enough information to convince users that the process of signing up will be beneficial.  If they had blocked out all content, users would not have sufficient information to make an informed decision. As a result, users may very well feel less inclined to sign up. At the complete opposite end, providing too much information will result in a similar situation, leaving a user with no reason to sign up.

I also believe this "Sign Up Wall" can be minimized with a well structured sign up experience.

Using 3rd party authorization(Facebook,Google,etc.) is a great way to speed up the sign-up process by allowing users to quickly sign up with minimal effort.  Even if your application requires more information from a users, you can still get an initial sign-up.

Here is example of how I would possibly structure my sign-up process for a review site to increase sign-ups while minimizing the "Sign Up Wall" experience.

```
User Status: Non Member/General Public 
Available Content: Read Reviews 

User Status: 3rd Party Authentication 
Available Content: Read Reviews, Like/Dislike Reviews

User Status: 3rd Party Authentication & Completed User Profile
Available Content: Read/Post Review, Like/Dislike Review,  Contact Members
```

Comment: Very good answer